# What exactly constitutes a bad TCP segment?

Tags: tcp, netstat, stress-testing

What constitutes a bad segment as in `bad segments received` in the `netstat` output below?  I would think a TCP header's checksum could do it, but are there other things?  If a segment arrives after its timeout? Or if a duplicate segment arrives?

```
$ netstat -s

<snip...>
Tcp:
    183975 active connections openings
    110830 passive connection openings
    5140 failed connection attempts
    2649 connection resets received
    19 connections established
    18272496 segments received
    18712556 segments send out
    25163 segments retransmited
    824 bad segments received.
    9557 resets sent
<snip...>
```